# Basic image processing in Qt, how do I break up an image into an array, ready to perform a Fourier transform on it?

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, image-processing

I am trying to do some very basic, but ridiculously cool, image processing with Qt (I have to use Qt, no Matlab allowed). I need to load a black and white image (Already done) and then perform a Fourier transform on it which I then display. The next step I'm looking at is filtering out some high frequencies, reverse transform and see what the results look like.

I assume that the starting point to this is breaking up the image into an array of discrete values in the spatial domain.

Does anybody have any experience in doing what I am describing? Do you guys agree with the array approach? Do I need a fancy library, or is it going to boil down to a numerical approach with various loops transforming each pixel?

I am a bit of a noob in Qt so it would be awesome of you could keep it simple.

Comment: "array of discrete values in the spatial domain." - what does it mean?

Comment: By spacial domain I simply mean representing each pixel as an x,y coordinate. These coordinates will then be the index to the array containing the intensity (0-255, since its grayscale) of each pixel.How do I break up a single image like this?

Answer (score 1):

Just load your picture into a QImage object. With the [pixel method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qimage.html#pixel-2) you will get the pixel value in RGB at position x,y. Using qGray(int r, int g, int b) will give you the grey value (0-255). For FFT, just take a look at [numerical recipes](http://www.nr.com).

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this link

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20529/slicing-up-an-image-into-rows-and-columns-in-java

you have to just change the image location as

GridImage image = new GridImage("img/card-grid-image-mass-effect.jpg",4, 15);

change File Name . then comile and execute code

Comment: Is gridimage qt relevant? Can't seem to find such a thing. Sorry, but just to be very clear, I simply want to take an image and generate an array with each entry storing the brightness (0-255) of the corresponding pixel.